# Hazelcast AWS ec2 auto discovery

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

Trying to run Hazelcast member from AWS ec2 instance with following simple configuration with auto-discovery.

**hazelcast.xml**

```
<hazelcast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
                                   http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.11.xsd"
               xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
        <properties>
            <property name="hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled">true</property>
        </properties>

        <network>
            <join>
                <multicast enabled="false" />
                <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
                <aws enabled="true">
                    <access-key>xxxxxxx</access-key>
                    <secret-key>xxxxxxx</secret-key>
                    <region>eu-west-1a</region>
                    <security-group-name>my-group</security-group-name>
                    <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                    <tag-value>hz-node</tag-value>
                </aws>
            </join>
        </network>
    </hazelcast>
```

**Member.java**

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;

public class Member {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
}
```

But when I'm executing the program from ec2 instance, getting the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-20:~$ java -jar sdsi.jar
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:09 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:10 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.11] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is f                     alse
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:10 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.11] Picked [172.31.19.20]:5701, using socket ServerSocket                     [addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:11 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Hazelcast 3.11 (20181023 - 1500bbb) start                     ing at [172.31.19.20]:5701
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:11 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc.                      All Rights Reserved.
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:11 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] A non-empty group password is configured                      for the Hazelcast member. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.8.2, members with th                     e same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentic                     ation) form a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed complete                     ly in a future release.
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:11 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Backpressur                     eRegulator
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Backpressure is disabled
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationE                     xecutorImpl
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generi                     c threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Diagnostics started
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.BuildInfoPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SystemPropertiesPlugi                     n
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.ConfigPropertiesPlugi                     n
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.MetricsPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SlowOperationPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.MemberHazelcastInstan                     ceInfoPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SystemLogPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active: logPartitions:false
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.MemberHazelcastInstan                     ceInfoPlugin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active, period-millis:10000
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.OperationHeartbeatPlu                     gin
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Plugin:active: period-millis:10000 max-de                     viation:33%
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:12 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [172.31.19.20]:5701 [dev] [3.11] [172.31.19.20]:5701 is STARTING
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:14 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [1] retrying in 1 seconds...
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:15 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [2] retrying in 2 seconds...
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:18 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [3] retrying in 3 seconds...
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:21 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [4] retrying in 5 seconds...
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:26 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [5] retrying in 7 seconds...
Oct 30, 2018 1:25:34 PM com.hazelcast.aws.utility.RetryUtils
WARNING: Couldn't connect to the AWS service, [6] retrying in 11 seconds...
```

Is there any workaround? Or am I missing anything from the configuration? 
Retry keeps going. Enabled diagnostic message, still unable to figure out what's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the region as `eu-west-1`, since the AWS endpoints are per-region, not per AZ. So, your configuration should be such as:

```
<hazelcast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
                                   http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.11.xsd"
               xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
        <properties>
            <property name="hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled">true</property>
        </properties>

        <network>
            <join>
                <multicast enabled="false" />
                <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
                <aws enabled="true">
                    <access-key>xxxxxxx</access-key>
                    <secret-key>xxxxxxx</secret-key>
                    <region>eu-west-1</region>
                    <security-group-name>my-group</security-group-name>
                    <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                    <tag-value>hz-node</tag-value>
                </aws>
            </join>
        </network>
    </hazelcast>
```